# SearchView in fragment (inflated menu in activity)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, searchview

I get NPE on `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`.

*/res/menu/order_toolbar.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/order_menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/order_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.widget.v7.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/order_menu_checkmark"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_checkmark"
    android:title="@string/order_toolbar"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

*ActivityOrder.java*

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order_toolbar, menu);
    mMenuCheckmark = menu.findItem(R.id.order_menu_checkmark);
    mMenuCheckmark.setVisible(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

*FragmentOrder.java*

```
    @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.order_menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I'm inflating menu in `Activity` (i need to hide checkmark and enable it later after the user made some input, all the logic is in the activity), and in Fragment, I have `RecyclerView` and I need to implement search (in the toolbar). So basically, I need to access that `SearchView` INSIDE FRAGMENT only.
I have been trying to find anything but nothing helps, if I inflate `menu` in `fragment` then I get doubled icons in the `toolbar`.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

is already added in `onCreate`

Also i tried this:
 1. inflate the menu in fragment (removed onCreateOptionsMenu in activity)
 2. passed menuItem (checkmark) back to activity trough interface so i can access checkmark
 3. still getting NPE if i set listener on searchview

Comment: If you can, you write your code in onCreateOptionsMenu. not in onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: As i already said, if I inflate in Fragment i get doubled icons. Purpose of Fragment is to get serializable list from activity and pass it to RecyclerView's adapter, because I need to show different types of ordering (based on values from Firebase)

Comment: You can make option menu in fragment. You use 'setHasOptionsMenu(true)' in Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
   mMenuSearch = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.order_menu_search).getActionView();
        mMenuSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

added `implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` on Fragment and 2 new Override methods `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChanged`

Comment: Could you please explain better, this is not clear at all.

Comment: just extend the class with SearchView.OnQueryTextListener and override those 2 methods (you will have to)

Answer (score 2):

I make option menu in fragment. Like this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
...
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.ic_bar_search));
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_1).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            return false;
        }
    });
....
}
```

Not sure, you call "searchView.setOnQueryTextListener" from onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: but if i inflate menu in fragment, then how do i get a reference to menuitem (checkmark) in activity?

Comment: I edited my question, i did inflating in fragment (removed it from activity) but i still can't get reference from SearchView, NPE allways

Comment: Don't call that in "onPrepareOptionsMenu". Call that in "onCreateOptionsMenu"